# Projection vectors

Tags: projection

[image: Question]

So I have done part of this question. Using the projection vector equation, I found that the projection vector of (4,2,-1) onto V was:
(1,-1,-1)

And a vector orthogonal to V is:
(3,3,0)=(4,2,-1)-(1,-1,-1)
But, just not sure how to find the point in V which is closest to (4,2,-1). Any help????

Comment: You are on the right track! Note that the cartesian equation for V is $x+y=0$ then use the given hint.

Comment: @gimusi does that still contain (0,0,2)?? thanks for your help

Comment: Yes of course indeed $0+0=0$ satisfy the equation. Since the plane is spanned by (0,0,2) all points (0,0,t) belongs to the plane, that is z coordinate is free, that is the plane is parallel to x-y plain. we can see that in many ways, for example also using cross product.

Comment: In the future please take the time to enter important parts of your question as text instead of pasting in pictures of it. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen-reading devices. You can find a quick reference on using MathJax to format mathematical expressions [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The orthogonal projection _is_ the nearest point.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that $(3,3,0)$ is orthogonal to the plane

$$(4,2,-1)+t(3,3,0)$$

for some $t$ belongs to it.